# What happens when a window closes before finishing reading the data?

Tags: java, window, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Apache Flink to read a Kafka topic which contains an Id and a list of objects as follows:

```
{
    Id: "12345",
    Objetcs: [
        {
            fatherId: "1a",
            id: "111",
            name: "aabc"
        },
        {
            fatherId: "1b",
            id: "222",
            name: "abffc"
        },
        {
            fatherId: "1a",
            id: "333",
            name: "gfds"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Then we convert it to a data stream of tuples containing the listId and the product. Finally we do a KeyBy and a TumblingProcessingTimeWindows of 10 seconds to group the data by the listId and fhaterId and convert the result of grouping the data to a string as follows:
“{ [ {fhaterId: “1a”, id: “222”, name: “aabc”}, {fhaterId: “1a”, id: “333”, name: “gfds”} ], [ {fhaterId: “1a ”, id: “222”, name: “aabc”} ] }”

The problem is that in some tests, we send 5 lists with 128,000 data each, where the expected result should be 5 string, but there are times when 6 arrive because one of the messages is divided.
In the example above it would be something like:
String 1: “{[{fhaterId: “1a”, id: “222”, name: “aabc”}], [{fhaterId: “1a”, id: “222”, name: “aabc”}]}”
String 2: “{[{fhaterId: “1a”, id: “333”, name: “gfds”}]}”

When the expected response is a single string.

what could be the reason?

The flow code is as follows:

```
DataStream<Result> sourceNegotiation = listNegotiationProducts
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<ListNegotiationProduct, Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void flatMap(ListNegotiationProduct listNegotiationProduct, Collector<Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct>> out) throws Exception {
                        listNegotiationProduct.getProducts().forEach(lnp -> {
                            Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct> response = new Tuple2<>(listNegotiationProduct.getTransactionId(), lnp);
                            out.collect(response);
                        });
                    }
                })
                .keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct>, Tuple2<UUID, Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<UUID, Integer> getKey(Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct> value) throws Exception {
                        return Tuple2.of(value.f0, value.f1.getNegotiationId());
                    }
                })
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(1))
                .apply(new WindowFunction<Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct>, Tuple2<UUID, Negotiation>, Tuple2<UUID, Integer>, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(Tuple2<UUID, Integer> uuidIntegerTuple2, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple2<UUID, NegotiationProduct>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<UUID, Negotiation>> collector) throws Exception {
                        Negotiation negotiation = new Negotiation();
                        Tuple2<UUID, Negotiation> response = new Tuple2<>();

                        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

                        iterable.iterator().forEachRemaining(negotiationProduct -> {

                            negotiation.setNegotiationId(negotiationProduct.f1.getNegotiationId());
                            response.setField(negotiationProduct.f0, 0);

                            List<String> observationList = new ArrayList<>();

                            observationList.add(negotiationProduct.f1.getObservation());

                            productList.add(Product
                                    .builder()
                                    .productGtin(negotiationProduct.f1.getProductGtin())
                                    .state(negotiationProduct.f1.getState())
                                    .observation(observationList)
                                    .retailerCode(negotiationProduct.f1.getRetailerCode()).build());
                        });

                        negotiation.setNegotiationProgressProducts(productList);

                        response.setField(negotiation, 1);
                        collector.collect(response);
                    }
                })
                .keyBy(t -> t.f0)
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(1))
                .apply(new WindowFunction<Tuple2<UUID, Negotiation>, Result, UUID, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(UUID uuid, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple2<UUID, Negotiation>> iterable, Collector<Result> collector) throws Exception {
                        List<Negotiation> negotiations = new ArrayList<>();
                        iterable.iterator().forEachRemaining(n -> {
                            negotiations.add(n.f1);
                        });
                        collector.collect(BuildResult.build(new Payload(negotiations), uuid));
                    }
                })
                .returns(Result.class);
```

Comment: Please don't use images to present code or JSON data. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` are aligned to the system clock. Sometimes you are going to be unlucky, and an event will arrive at 11:48:09.988 (for example), right before the end of one window and the beginning of another. Some of the tuples created from it will fall into one window, and the rest into the following window.

---

Flink's DataStream windowing API just isn't a good match for this use case. It will be easier to solve this by either going up or down in the API stack.

If you go up a level to the Table API, then you can use [over windows](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/over-agg/), which allow grouping over a time interval relative to a specific event.

And if you go down a level and use a KeyedProcessFunction, then you can work with state and time directly. E.g., you could key the stream as you are doing now, and then gather together in ListState all of the events that arrive in a 10-second interval.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, does it mean that even if I set the window to 10 minutes, would there still be the possibility of the data being split into different tuples? If so, what is recommended to do in that case?

Comment: Instead of using default ProcessingTIme, maybe you can use System.currentTimeMillis() as event time. Then window and allowedLateness() may work ?

Comment: @sergiogarcia I've expanded my answer. Personally, I would use a KeyedProcessFunction for this use case. If you get stuck, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

try .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(2)) after window()

**Edit**: See David`s note below.

Comment: Allowed lateness is only relevant when event time and watermarks are being used. It does nothing with processing time windows.

Comment: I agree but still processing time can extend the windows periods for a couple of milliseconds because of IO delays? There is not enough detail in the question but using processingtime also does not guarantee 5 matching window. I would still try adding allowedLateness.

Comment: I've read the source code. I can guarantee you it won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but as David says, it doesn't work this way, since it is something we have implemented and still the problem occurs.
I have edited the question to add the source code